# How to parse JSON like variable in Perl?

Tags: perl

I read from a WEB server which returns me data like this:

```
{'status':{"t":1, "f":1, "p":2, "i":1}}
```

It seems not a valid JSON format data, told by JSON::XS. How can I parse that?

Comment: File a bug with the web service and get them to fix it? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSON::XS` doesn't seem to have a toggle for accepting single quotes, but `JSON` does.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON -support_by_pp

my $source = q( {'status':{"t":1, "f":1, "p":2, "i":1}} );
my $parsed = JSON->new->allow_singlequote->decode($source);
```

For more options and details, see the [JSON module docs](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON).

Answer (score 3):

You can check the specification for the JSON format [here](http://www.json.org/). In your case, the problem is likely the single quotes around `status`. If you use regular double quotes instead, it should parse:

```
{"status":{"t":1, "f":1, "p":2, "i":1}}
```

You can check the validity of your JSON at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: In fact, I have a very very large data (a 8KB size single line) read from the WEB Server, which mixed `'status':`,`'sth':{"sth":"as\"'df"....`.I'm not sure  `s/'/"/g` will work

Comment: I'd suggest you fix this on the server side rather than trying to do regexp replace on the client side. Chances are, if others are using this service, they will encounter the same issue. So fix the problem at the source.

Answer (score 1):

It's valid JavaScript. So if you don't want to write your own parser,  pass it to a [JavaScript engine](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JavaScript) for evaluation and conversion to JSON.

Comment: It's valid JavaScript, but it's not valid JSON.

Comment: @RickF ... so? How does it matter, or how does Ikegami claim otherwise?

Comment: @RickF, I know. Please re-read what I posted. My post would make no sense if I believed it was valid JSON.

Comment: @RickF that javascript engine does not require valid JSON

Comment: @ikegami Fair enough, though it is still a pretty cryptic answer.

Comment: What's cryptic about it? The only thing I didn't do is provide the implementation.