# Json Sort in Perl

Tags: perl

I need to sort json values which is in array elements. I need to sort by json field id. Is it possible to sort?

Can please anyone help in this case?

Kindly find below code.

```
$json1 = '{"id":"3","name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" }';
$json2 = '{"id":"2","name":"Prem", "age":26, "city":"India" }';
$json3 = '{"id":"4","name":"Mark", "age":27, "city":"USA" }';
$json4 = '{"id":"1","name":"Anto", "age":28, "city":"UK" }';
@array_of_json = ($json1,$json2,$json3,$json4);
```

After sorting by id, Need Output like this,

```
{"id":"1","name":"Anto", "age":28, "city":"UK" }
{"id":"2","name":"Prem", "age":26, "city":"India" }
{"id":"3","name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" }
{"id":"4","name":"Mark", "age":27, "city":"USA" }
```

Comment: Your example is no Perl code.

Comment: Can you please check now?

Comment: You know, that it is a silly idea to order object members? They are defined as an "unordered set of name/value pairs". http://www.json.org/index.html

Answer (score 4):

Your current sample data can be sorted by using the default behaviour of the `sort` function.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dumper;

my @array_of_json = (
  '{"id":"3","name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" }',
  '{"id":"2","name":"Prem", "age":26, "city":"India" }',
  '{"id":"4","name":"Mark", "age":27, "city":"USA" }',
  '{"id":"1","name":"Anto", "age":28, "city":"UK" }',
);

my @sorted = sort @array_of_json;

say Dumper \@sorted;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '{"id":"1","name":"Anto", "age":28, "city":"UK" }',
          '{"id":"2","name":"Prem", "age":26, "city":"India" }',
          '{"id":"3","name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" }',
          '{"id":"4","name":"Mark", "age":27, "city":"USA" }'
        ];
```

But if you want anything more complex, I'd recommend decoding the JSON and sorting the data structures.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use JSON 'decode_json';
use Data::Dumper;

my @array_of_json = map { decode_json $_ }  (
  '{"id":"3","name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" }',
  '{"id":"2","name":"Prem", "age":26, "city":"India" }',
  '{"id":"4","name":"Mark", "age":27, "city":"USA" }',
  '{"id":"1","name":"Anto", "age":28, "city":"UK" }',
);

my @sorted = sort { $a->{id} <=> $b->{id } } @array_of_json;

say Dumper \@sorted;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following,

```
my @sorted = sort {

    my ($m)=$a=~m/"id":"(\d+)/;  

    my ($n)=$b=~m/"id":"(\d+)/;  

     $m<=>$n                  

    } @array_of_json;

print join"\n",@sorted , "\n";
```

Store the numbers after id into `$m` and `$n` and make a sort for those variables.

Then always put `use warnings` and `use strict` in your program, declare the variable.

Comment: This is better than my answer, interesting problem :)

Comment: Any reason why you've declared `$m` and `$n` outside of the sort subroutine?

Comment: @DaveCross There is no reason,  corrected, Now I declare the variable inside the scope. Because we don't want to use the variable outside the scope. Is it correct?  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments about sorting json, but for the sake of a perl teaser.

There is probably a more elegant way of doing it but this will work

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
undef $/;

my @array_of_json=('{"id":"3","name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" }','{"id":"2","name":"Prem", "age":26, "city":"India" }','{"id":"4","name":"Mark", "age":27, "city":"USA" }','{"id":"1","name":"Anto", "age":28, "city":"UK" }');

for (sort mySort @array_of_json) {
    print "$_\n";
}

sub mySort {
        $a=~/"id":"(\d+)"/;
        my $ida=$1;
        $b=~/"id":"(\d+)"/;
        my $idb=$1;
        return $ida <=> $idb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having said, that it is a silly idea to sort JSON object members, this will do what you want:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON::XS;

my @array_of_json=('{"id":"3", "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York"}',
                   '{"id":"2", "name":"Prem", "age":26, "city":"India"}',
                   '{"id":"4", "name":"Mark", "age":27, "city":"USA"}',
                   '{"id":"1", "name":"Anto", "age":28, "city":"UK"}');


my $j = JSON::XS->new->utf8->allow_nonref;

for my $h (sort { $a->{id} <=> $b->{id} } map { $j->decode($_) } @array_of_json)
{
  print
      '{',
      join (',',
            map { $j->encode ($_) . ':' . $j->encode ($h->{$_}) }
            ('id', 'name', 'age', 'city')),
      "}\n";
}
```

You need the Perl module [JSON::XS](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS/XS.pm) to parse and encode JSON data. Install it with something like `apt-get install libjson-xs-perl`.

The above could be found already on SO:

- Parse JSON: [How to parse JSON like variable in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15756746/402322)
- Format JSON: [Perl's JSON::XS not encoding UTF8 correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31170479/402322)
- Sort hash: [How can I sort a hash's keys naturally?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383528/402322)
- Perl's map: [What's the point of Perl's map?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/136204/402322)